# Accessing structure array attributes without using pointers

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, structure

Is it possible to make a structure array variable and access structure attributes without using pointers? I tried doing it without a pointer and it is giving me an error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
struct Student
{
    string name;
    string rollNo;
    float GPA;
    string department;
    char section;
};

int main()
{
    Student s1[10];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << "Enter your name: ";
        cin >> s1.name;
        cout << "Enter roll num: ";
        cin >> s1.rollNo;
    }

return 0;
}
```

I am accessing attributes by placing a dot s1.rollNo gives an error.

Comment: What error does it give? I am pretty sure the error message explains the reason, if you read the error text.

Comment: s1 is an array and you need to use square brackets to access its elements

Comment: You created an array of 10 `Student` objects. Which of these is intended to be given a name by the line `cin >> s1.name;`? All ten at once?

Comment: If your code *with* pointers looks like `s1->name` and `s1->rollNo`, those are equivalent to `s1[0].name`  and `s1[0].rollNo`, and only use one of the array elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s1` is an array of structs and needs to be accessed with an index: `s1[i].name` etc.

Answer (score 0):

As said by others you need to access it like

```
s1[i].name
```

You could also access it like this

```
for(auto &s : s1){
    cin >> s.name; //Do Whatever With Member
}
```